# GC log rotation data lose on application restart

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, jvm-arguments

I use this jvm option in order to create gc logs and enable rolling:

```
$ java -Xloggc:gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5  XX:GCLogFileSize=128K
```

However, I have a problem when I restart my application. After a restart, the first log file `gc.log.0` is overwritten and the data of that file is not rolled to `gc.log.1` and hence lost.

I'm wondering if I'm right and if there's a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also use java own timestamps for that:

```
java -Xloggc:gc-%t.log ...(rest of your line)...
```

`%t` will be replaced with a timestamp by java (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6950794 for information and other formats supported by `-Xloggc`

Comment: My favorite solution to the problem, because it also works inside of properties files (such as wrapper.conf). Thanks!

Comment: When I tested this, the file for the pattern `gc_%t.log` looked like: `gc_2016-12-06_16-46-30.log.0.current` which contradicts the documentation you linked: `%t - date stamp when log file is created (format: YYYY-MM-DD)`

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here, I fixed it by adding the timestamp to the gc log file name like this (in this case /etc/default/tomcat7):

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`
JAVA_OPTS="-Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat7/gc-$DATE.log ..."
```

this way you keep your gc logs after restart as jvm starts with a different timestamp and does not overwrite gc.logs written before. you need to clean up these files manually from time to time (cronjob).